# How to share code in angular js (concept of code resuability in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angular js and i want to share and  make certain codes reusable. i have tried to do that using services and factory. But i am getting error.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.ctrls')
    .controller('Ctrl_HubStockOnHandMode', function($http, $scope, reportService) {

        $scope.HubStockOnHandModeGridOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                type: "jsonp",

                transport: {
                    read: function(e) {
                        reportService.WebAPI('abc/BIUMo', {
                            EnvironmentCode:'JMVH',                           
                            OrderBy: getOrderBy(e.data.sort)
                        }).then(function (d) {
                            $scope.data = d;
                            e.success(d.Data);
                            });
                    }
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            height:config.GridHeight,
            scrollable:true,
           sortable: {
                mode: "single",
                allowUnsort: true
            },
            filterable: {
                            extra: false,
                            operators: {
                                string: {
                                    startswith: "Starts with",
                                    eq: "Is equal to",
                                    neq: "Is not equal to",
                                    contains: "Contains"
                                }
                            }
                        },
            pageable: false,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "RowNumber"
                    ,title: "No."
                    ,width: "50px"
                    ,sortable:false
                    ,filterable: false
                },
                {
                    field: 'ItemCTSH'
                    ,title:'Item'                  
                    ,template: "<div kendo-tooltip  title='#= ItemCT #' > #= ItemCTSH #  </div>"
                    ,filterable: {
                                    ui: itemFilter
                               }
                },

  ]
        };

        }

        //Get Item List
        $http.get('http://webapi.dashboard.hcmisonline.org/api/OID_WebApi/IssuedItemList')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.items = data.Data;
            });
        function itemFilter(element) {
            element.kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: $scope.items
            });
        } 


        }    



});
```

I want to reuse the functions like the Get item. i have other pages/grids that use exactly this code, except changing the environment code 
how to i solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: Could you create a Fiddle or Plunker example?

Comment: Also what kind of error do you get?

Comment: kendoAutoComplete-is undefined.